# JHipster 3.0 websocket channel propagation from Microservice to GateWay

Tags: jhipster

by migrating an old JHipster 2.0 monolithic application to the new JHipster 3.0,
we are wondering how to implement an old JHipster 2.0 websocket into the 3.0 microservice.

Tks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. Migration of a project generated by JHipster 2.x  to 3.0 is not supported.

Comment: You are right. So my real question is: "how to implement websocket logic on a Jhipster 3.0 microservice stack in order to be published by the JHipster 3.0 Gateway"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just not possible to use websocket with JHipster gateways due to Zuul proxy.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/163

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. We will take a look